# Best device placement strategies for RNNs?

Tags: tensorflow

Consider a simple n-layer stacked RNN (LSTM, GRU etc.) for sequential prediction, what is the most efficient device placement strategy (if multiple GPUs are available)? I think if is preferred to dedicate one GPU to each layer of the RNN, but what about softmax and loss computation? Should they be placed on GPUs as well or CPUs? What is more, if we further add an attention mechanism, should the attention be placed on CPUs?

Comment: Have you tried profiling any combination?

Answer (score 0):

This is an active area of research; and in general it depends on the specifics of your network.  Probably you want to place the softmax and loss on the same GPU (if they'll fit); likely either on the GPU of the top layer, or on gpu:0.  Regarding attention, I don't think there's a very clear answer.  It depends on the size of your attention weights' sizes, etc.  In these cases, your best bet is just to try the two placements I suggested for the softmax/loss.  This leaves you a grid search with 4 possible locations.  Try them all and report back :)

Comment: Thanks! Before I even start trying different device placements for softmax/attention, I tried to compare the difference between using 1 GPU vs 4 GPUs for a multi-layer RNN. The model I experimented with has the following architecture: 1d convolution + dropout + 4 GRUs + softmax, and I tried to distribute 4 GPUs to these layers. However it was counter-intuitive that using 4 GPUs was actually slower than just 1 GPU (1 GPU timeline: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bycn-mCLj2bvWGxsbnRva3hWN2M), 4 GPU timeline: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bycn-mCLj2bvZXExYlhnRE5ZRm8))

Comment: Judging from the timeline profile, what confuses me is that in the 4-GPU version, computing a single layer RNN on one GPU took longer time than that in the 1-GPU version. Is there anything obvious that can be improved?